# Sql query returns row which was not specified by Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My SQL query doesn't return an output that suppose to be specified by my where clause.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    transaction_details.transaction_id
    ,transaction_details.transaction_number
    ,transaction_details.product_id
    ,Products3.ProductName
FROM transaction_details
INNER JOIN Products3
ON transaction_details.product_id = Products3.productID
INNER JOIN transaction_status
ON transaction_details.transaction_id = transaction_status.transaction_id
WHERE status_of_transaction = 'review'
```

This query should return me table rows with a `status_of_transaction = 'review'`.

Here is my table which contains the `status_of_transaction`
[image]

I tried `DISTINCT` but its not working.

and this is the output I always get:

[image]

is there something wrong with my query its is returning table row which was not specified by my *WHERE* clause?

Comment: `transaction_number` Remove this column or you should use `GROUP BY`

Comment: What happens if you include `status_of_transaction` in the `SELECT` clause?  What is the resulting data?  I suspect something else may be going on here, possibly related to the product of the `JOIN`s, as opposed to the `WHERE` clause simply not working at all.

Comment: @NEER going to try it

Comment: @NEER  That does not fix the issue, it just masks it.  The additional row is still being returned in the grouped dataset.

Comment: @David I see.Ill give it a go.

Comment: I tried both of it same result.

Comment: By convention, where only one table is referenced in a WHERE clause, I tend to use that as the core table and then join all the others onto that. While it shouldn't impact on the result (of an INNER JOIN), I find it easier to think about the problem this way.

Comment: Can you show sample data without `where clause`

Comment: You need to use alias of tablename for attribute status_of_transaction while using in WHERE condition, can you put this attribute in select list?

Comment: @NEER the answer you gave a while ago work.but its kinda hard to understand for a begginer like me

Comment: @Strawberry should I try to use a different main table where the `WHERE` clause apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple rows generated by the set (remember this is all set theory) - you are missing a Foreign Key/Primary Key (FK/PK) relationship in the JOIN.  I'll bet you missed a column in the INNER JOIN "ON" statement.  There are probably two columns necessary to JOIN on to find the proper solution.

I suggest either picking it apart table by table, or using select * and look for the difference in the column values between each row. One column should be different - which you currently cannot see (i.e. hidden) because the column is not in the current SELECT statement.

Try this...

```
SELECT 
    transaction_status.*
FROM transaction_details
INNER JOIN Products3
ON transaction_details.product_id = Products3.productID
INNER JOIN transaction_status
ON transaction_details.transaction_id = transaction_status.transaction_id
WHERE status_of_transaction = 'review'
```

I believe the issue is with the transaction_status join.  The transaction_id is the same for both rows in transaction_details - which matches TWO rows in transaction_status.  SQL will create 4 rows -- two rows that match "review" and two rows for "replied"  (remove the WHERE to see them).  This is a cross join of sorts.

Does the _status table also contain transaction_number?  There needs to be a way to JOIN to the single row in transaction_details to a single row in transaction_status.  Somehow that _status row belongs to the _details row.   Look at (or ask the DBA) the PK/FK definitions for both tables.

Not knowing your schema - I would guess the solution is....

```
SELECT 
transaction_details.transaction_id
,transaction_details.transaction_number
,transaction_details.product_id
,Products3.ProductName
FROM transaction_details
INNER JOIN Products3
ON transaction_details.product_id = Products3.productID
INNER JOIN transaction_status
ON transaction_details.transaction_id = transaction_status.transaction_id
-- ADDED NEXT LINE
  AND transaction_details.transaction_number = transaction_status.transaction_number
-- END Change
WHERE status_of_transaction = 'review'
```

Comment: Great explanation.This happened to me few days ago,kinda clear in my head now.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of the inner joins is matching more than one row, so it generates two rows in the output set.  Run the query with:

```
select  transaction_details.transaction_id
,       Products3.product_id
,       transaction_details.detail_id
```

to examine which join is the culprit.

Comment: I tried replacing the select statement like you said.still same output.

Comment: Yeah, changing the "select" part never changes the rows. But you should be able to see which source table is causing the duplicate rows